Creating anticolumns in R
I have a dataframe having columns like.
Gene1 Gene2 Gene3
1      0      1
1      1      0
0      0      1

I want to add similar number oif more columns corresponding to each column with opposite values such as.
Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene1_wt Gene2_wt Gene3_wt
1      0      1     0       1        0
1      1      0     0       0        1
0      0      1     1       1        0

I am looking for some code perhaps some mutate thing in dplyr or so to do this at once as my real data has around hundreds of such columns.

cbind(df, wt = 1 - df) should solve your problem

@Onyambu please post as an answer.

Just curious, why are you doing this? I see you are working with genes matrix type data, what analysis require this step?

@zx8754 Idea is to create a control (Samples having no mutation in that gene) variable against each gene annotation column. It will be helpful in creating some boxplots.

Negate !, then implicit integer conversion with +.
cbind(d, wt = +!d)
#   Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 wt.Gene1 wt.Gene2 wt.Gene3
# 1     1     0     1        0        1        0
# 2     1     1     0        0        0        1
# 3     0     0     1        1        1        0

(I'd advise to use @Onyambu's answer in the comments.)

A dplyr solution:
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(1 - across(Gene1:Gene3, .names = "{.col}_wt"))

#   Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene1_wt Gene2_wt Gene3_wt
# 1     1     0     1        0        1        0
# 2     1     1     0        0        0        1
# 3     0     0     1        1        1        0

